# Anyway to clone the shipping services at: admin/commerce/config/shipping

Tags: commerce

Is there any way to clone Flat Rates shipping services at: 'admin/commerce/config/shipping' ?

The Flat Rates are generated by these modules: [commerce_shipping](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping)
and [commerce_flat_rate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate)

I need this because I need to create 50 shipping services (for the 50 Spain provinces/states).

Comment: Why don't you just create 50 different shipping rates? What you are asking now is to clone complete shipping configuration.

Comment: @Topsitemakers how can I do that?

Comment: Here's an example: with [flat rate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) module you can create new flat rates here `admin/commerce/config/shipping`. Each of those flat rates is turned into a Rules component which can have conditions, where you can check if the delivery address is within a particular province. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @Topsitemakers yes, this is what I need. But then I need to create 50 flat rates. Am I right? The only change in each one will be the Post Code, that's is why I thought of clonning them and then after change the Post Code for each one.

Comment: Yes, you will need 50 flat rates. The difference between this and what you've asked initially is that you won't have to write any code and you will just use what is provided by Commerce automatically. Also let me know if this solves your problem and I will post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, then my question is: is there any way to clone these flat rates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this programmatically. As you will need this to be done only once, you can just run this from `devel/php` or in a custom module.

Zones are just there as an example; prepare an array with two letter zone codes / some other identifier and run the same code:

```
$zones = range(2, 10);
foreach ($zones as $zone) {
  $shipping_service = array(
    'name'            => 'flat_rate_for_zone_' . $zone,
    'title'           => 'Title for zone ' . $zone,
    'display_title'   => 'Display title for zone ' . $zone,
    'description'     => 'Description for zone ' . $zone,
    'rules_component' => TRUE,
    'data'            => array(),
    'is_new'          => TRUE,
    'amount'          => 900,
    'currency_code'   => commerce_default_currency(),
  );
  commerce_flat_rate_service_save($shipping_service);
}
```

Hope this helps.